# Is there any way to show the file browser INSIDE a tkinter window rather than an open file dialogue?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a program in Tkinter that has a file browser/explorer on the left side of the window and a section to the right which displays the contents of the file.
I've only been able to find solutions that open a separate file dialogue window and would like to actually display the file explorer in the main window.
Not really sure how to go about this so any help would be appreciated.
Cheers!

Comment: You can use `ttk.Treeview` to make the file explorer.

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this -- tkinter has many widgets that you can combine to make a file browser. This question is far too vague and shows no sign of having done any research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the standard Tkinter function for navigating a directory uses the file explorer system of the operating system to do this, so there is no easy way (to my knowledge) to simply embed this within your application. You would need to build your own file navigation software if you require something like this, or find a third party package that can do it for you.

To implement it yourself you could use the os module to determine the contents of a directory on the user's system. The specifics will depend on your requirements, but for the sake of example if you only need to access the folder your script is run from:

```
import os
script_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
# Now, let's build our file/folder list
dir_contents = []
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(script_directory):
    dir_contents = [subdir, dirs, files]
    break
```

Here the code will iterate over the directory `script_directory`, and all folders. Since in this example we are only interested in `script_directory` itself, we use `break` to stop after this single iteration.

`subdir` will be the subdirectory name for each iteration of `os.walk`.
`dirs` will be a list of all folders at `subdir`.
`files` will be a list of all files at `subdir`.

You will then need to implement buttons and other widgets to display the results and allow navigation and file operations, which may necessitate other calls to the `os` module to establish the contents of the directories the user navigates to. If you need to access more than one directory location, I'd suggest implementing a class to handle this rather than trying to flesh it all out in a deeply nested list.

Of course, this is a big job, so I would only recommend it if it is absolutely essential for the project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I might have to look into a different route.